# How to fix mixed lat / lng order

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, postgis, openstreetmap

I have some OSM data imported with osm2pgsql:

```
osm2pgsql -d geomdb -l -U DBUSER -H DBHOST -S my.style germany.shp
```

The default srid is 4326:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

that is used also by openstreetmap, mapquest, google (I have read this somewhere).
Now geometries in my DB look like (e.g.)

```
LINESTRING(10.02 54.34,10.01 54.33,10.03 54.38)
```

instead of:

```
LINESTRING(54.34 10.02,54.33 10.01,54.38 10.03)
```

The lat / lng values for each point are switched. Why? Can I fix this without reimporting data again?

I don't want to do it in my application before/after every single query.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function [ST_FlipCoordinates](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html) to swap YX to XY axis order.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately it's available only in PostGIS 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done, you have to brake the linestring into individual points, then make a new point by switching X and Y, make a linestring again and then replace the linestring with the new one. Like this, just replace the names with yours.

```
UPDATE the_table AS t
SET the_linestring=l.the_linestring
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          st_makeline(point) AS the_linestring
   FROM
     ( SELECT t.id,
              st_makepoint(st_y(st_pointn(the_linestring,buz)) ,st_x(st_pointn(the_linestring,index_num))) AS point
      FROM the_table t
      JOIN
        (SELECT id,
                generate_series(1,st_npoints(the_linestring)) AS index_num
         FROM the_table) AS q ON t.id=q.id ) AS q
   GROUP BY q.id ) AS l
WHERE t.id=l.id;
```

Comment: Ok, I'll consider this a a fix. But why is the data imported with screwed coordinates? I don't think this is the way it should work.

Comment: @dompie I have no idea to be honest.